# ASPX C# Control ID Naming - generate different Id with different Machines

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a ASP TextBox in my machine as below:

```
<INPUT onchange=jsCheckSpecialApproval();id=ctl00_MainContent_SpecialApprovalTB
style="WIDTH: 100%" readOnlymaxLength=10000 name=ctl00$MainContent$SpecialApprovalTB>
```

But when I deployed to other machines, the text box changed to as follow:

```
<INPUT onchange=jsCheckSpecialApproval();id=MainContent_SpecialApprovalTB
style="WIDTH: 100%" readOnlymaxLength=10000 name=ctl00$MainContent$SpecialApprovalTB>
```

Apparently the text box control id generated differently with different machine.

```
(ctl00_MainContent_SpecialApprovalTB = > MainContent_SpecialApprovalTB)
```

Hence this causes an issue which some computer might not able to read this textbox since I wrote `getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_SpecialApprovalTB")`
in javascript to read or set this text box.

So why is this happening? Is there any way to do this better and how to prevent this from happening again?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use control Id in javascript then you have to set Client ID mode static.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Control.ClientIDMode Property
```

The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

If you want to define it in aspx page then you can do:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" ></div>
```